# Instance Counter for a String - Java

Tags: java, string, instance

String

- name of the car. The name is formed by concatenating the word “Car” to the instance number of this object. For example, the first instance is Car1, the second instance is Car2, and so forth.

So I created a String named car and now I need to make it apply a incrementing number when a new instance is created.

```
public class CarDash {
public String Car ="Car"; 
public static int instanceNumber;
}
```

And then it needs to count how many instances were created

- One class variable that is shared for all of the class instances.
  instanceNumber
  integer
  keeps track the number of instances created.

Should i add a counter whenever a certain method is called? Or have it count when the a new Car is named/created?

```
    instanceNumber++;
```

I dont know if I am making any sense...

Comment: call `instanceNumber++;` in your constrcutor

Comment: Does a constructor require a return statement?

Comment: *Does a constructor require a return statement?*  **No there should not be enough logic in a constructor to require any return statements**

Comment: What are your expected output? Do you want your variable name will name itself like Car + 1?

Comment: I want it to output Car1, Car2, Car3, etc

Comment: factory pattern is one of solutions

Comment: you cannot simply count constructor-calls.... whenever an object is finalized you should **decrease** the instance counter. and this cannot be done easily expect you manage construction/destruction explicit!

Comment: hence rephrase your question into 'constructor-call' counter ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create a constructor and increment the instanceNumber (using `++instanceNumber` pre-increment ) then set the car value using instanceNumber variable.

So your constructor will be similar to below.

```
public CarDash(){
    Car="Car"+ (++instanceNumber);
}
```

Whole class will be as below

```
public class CarDash {
public String Car = "Car";
public static int instanceNumber;

public CarDash(){
    this.Car="Car"+ (++instanceNumber);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CarDash car=new CarDash();
    CarDash car1=new CarDash();
    CarDash car2=new CarDash();

    System.out.println(car.Car+" "+car1.Car+" "+car2.Car);
}
}
```

Out put will be as below.

```
Car1 Car2 Car3
```

Comment: Please, make instanceNumber private! And "Car" should be a constant: final and uppercase by convention

Answer (score 0):

Try like below.

```
public class CarDash {
public String Car ="Car"; 
public static int instanceNumber;

CarDash() {
    instanceNumber++;
    Car = Car + instanceNumber;
}

public static int getInstanceCount() {
   return instanceNumber;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do instanceNumber++; in your constructor.
But take special care in case you are instanceNumber as stati,as this would be shared by all instances.
So,in your case(suppose you have 10 instances),you will get name as Car10  for all instances.
e.g.

```
public class CarDash {
    public String Car ="Car";
    public static int instanceNumber;

public CarDash() {
    instanceNumber++;
}

public String print(){
    return  Car+instanceNumber;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CarDash carDash=new CarDash();
    CarDash carDash1=new CarDash();
    CarDash carDash2=new CarDash();
    System.out.println(carDash.print());
    System.out.println(carDash1.print());
    System.out.println(carDash2.print());
}
```

}

Output ::
Car3
Car3
Car3

Better way :

```
public class CarDash2 {
public String Car ="Car";
public static int instanceNumber;
public int carId;

public CarDash2() {
    instanceNumber++;
    carId=instanceNumber;
}

public String print(){
    return Car+carId;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CarDash2 carDash=new CarDash2();
    CarDash2 carDash1=new CarDash2();
    CarDash2 carDash2=new CarDash2();
    System.out.println(carDash.print());
    System.out.println(carDash1.print());
    System.out.println(carDash2.print());
}
```

}

Output:: 
Car1
Car2
Car3

Comment: The better way is outputting Car3 for all of the instances

Comment: Are you kidding @B.Kel ?It can't, since it is primitive int.

Comment: I have run it and am getting Car1 Car2 Car3.

Comment: Make sure you are compiling and running properly.